# Algorithm or method for matrix decomposition of a unitary complex matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to decompose a matrix T into the form `u1*v*u2*v...v*u_n`, where `v=F*H*F` is a given matrix, here `F` is just the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix (a unitary complex matrix) and `H` is  unitary complex diagonal matrix. What I am trying to optimize for is `u1,u2,...,un` (all of them are diagonal matrices), we can define arbitrarily how many matrices `ui` we have, but the less of them we have, the better.
For example, for n=3, then we want to get to `T=u1*v*u2*v*u3`

I have tried first to solve it for n=3 and matrix dimensions of 3x3 (although I would later need to use it for 64x64 matrices). For this, I used polar decomposition such that `T= U*P`, and then decompose P into a matrix of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and use them to construct the diagonal matrices `u1` and `u2`, and then `u3`, but my results are not quite right.

I am not sure what methods or algorithms I could use, I really would appreciate your help on this matter.
Thanks.